# Determining which listbox's event has been launched

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

In my C# Winforms application, I have a tablelayoutpanel which will contain listboxes from anywhere between 2 to 64. A user can double-click any items inside the Listbox, which then transfers the information of the item to a modaless window that was already opened.

My question is the following:

1. How do I know which listbox the event has been called from?
2. Is there a way to figure out which row/column the listbox is inside the tablelayoutpanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I know which listbox the event has been called from?

```
void ListBox_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lb = (ListBox)sender;  // that's the one
}
```

---

> Is there a way to figure out which row/column the listbox is inside the tablelayoutpanel?

That one I'm not so sure of as I haven't worked much with that class.  You can certainly get the bounding rectangle of the `ListBox` within its parent container, but I took a glance at the documentation for `TableLayoutPanel` and I didn't see anything obvious (i.e., something like a `Columns` property).

Answer (score 2):

> How do I know which listbox the event has been called from?

Ed S. already answered that. Maybe to mention that you need to attach the event-handler to your listbox:

```
var newListbox = new ListBox();
newListbox.DoubleClick += ListBox_SomeEvent;
_myTableLayouter.Controls.Add(newListBox);
```

> Is there a way to figure out which row/column the listbox is inside the tablelayoutpanel?

Use [TableLayoutPanel.GetCellPosition()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcellposition.aspx). You'll get back a [TableLayoutPanelCellPositiontion here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanelcellposition.aspx) with Row and Column.

Comment: *"And if you freeing your listboxes you need to detach them to allow GC happen for the listboxes:*" - This is incorrect.  The event *publisher* holds a reference to the *subscriber* via the delegate, not the other way around. +1 for mentioning `GetCellPosition` though, I missed that.

Comment: And on a side note, if I ever see `_mylistbox35` I may just have to delete the entire file :D

Comment: Subscribing events: you are right. in this scenario one does not need to remove / undo the subscription if that code (event-handler) is placed in the parent. will fix my response.

Comment: About the _mylistbox35: you're right as well. Fixed my sample to better illustrate what I meant with that line of code.